# Trying to display/show search result on another page in javascript/polymerjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to show/display my search result on another page when you click the search button.

Right now what my code is doing is that it search from the input value from the json array and return the value if it is found or return a message if it is not found.

But i want that search result to show on another page like "search-result.html" instead of the same page.

here is what i have so far and the search is working fine.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/v1.2.2/polymer.html" />
  <script src="https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-elements/iron-elements.html">

  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <style>
    .taller {
      height: 120px;
    }

    [vertical-align="top"] ul {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    [vertical-align="bottom"] ul {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    button,
    paper-button {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #eee;
      /*padding: 1em;*/
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="employee-list">
    <template>
      <input type="text" id="searchEmp" placeholder="Search For employee" />
      <br/>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select Department</option>
        <option value="digital engamenet">Digital Engagement</option>
        <option value="shared research">Shared Research</option>
        <option value="research">Research</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <button onclick="javascript:searchData()">Search</button>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <paper-listbox>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="font-size:15px;font-family:'Open Sans'">
              {{item.name}} - {{item.dept}}
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </template>
      </paper-listbox>
      <!-- would like this result show on another page on click of search -->
      <div class="search-result">
        <h3>Result</h3>
        <div id="result"></div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'employee-list',
        properties: {
          items: {
            type: Array
          }
        },
        ready: function() {
          this.items = [{
            'name': 'Jack',
            'dept': 'Digital Engagement'
          }, {
            'name': 'Buba',
            'dept': 'Research'
          }, {
            'name': 'Kashif',
            'dept': 'Shared Research'
          }];
        }

      });
      var items = [{
        'name': 'Jack',
        'dept': 'Digital Engagement'
      }, {
        'name': 'Buba',
        'dept': 'Research'
      }, {
        'name': 'Kashif',
        'dept': 'Shared Research'
      }];

      function searchData() {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById('searchEmp').value.toLowerCase(),
          i, len, data, prop, matches = [],
          val;

        for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
          data = items[i];
          for (prop in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
              val = data[prop];
              if (typeof val !== 'undefined' && val.toLowerCase && val.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal) >= 0) {
                // this data matches
                matches.push(data);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        showMatches(matches);
      }

      function showMatches(matches) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('result'),
          i, len, content = '';
        if (typeof matches === 'undefined' || !matches.length) {
          elem.innerHTML = '<i>No results found</i>';
          return;
        }
        for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++) {
          content += '<div><b>Name:</b>' + matches[i].name + '</div>';
        }
        elem.innerHTML = content;
      }
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <employee-list></employee-list>
</body>

</html>
```

**search-result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/v1.2.2/polymer.html" />
  <script src="https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-elements/iron-elements.html">

  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <style>
    .taller {
      height: 120px;
    }

    [vertical-align="top"] ul {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    [vertical-align="bottom"] ul {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    button,
    paper-button {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #eee;
      /*padding: 1em;*/
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="employee-list">
    <template>
      <input type="text" id="searchEmp" placeholder="Search For employee" />
      <br/>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select Department</option>
        <option value="digital engamenet">Digital Engagement</option>
        <option value="shared research">Shared Research</option>
        <option value="research">Research</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <button onclick="javascript:searchData()">Search</button>
    </template>
    <div class="research-result">
      <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout__item u-1/4">
          <h3>Result</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="notFound" class="searchResult">
      <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout__item u-1">
          <p>No applicable NDA found for "{{filterValue}}"</p>
        </div>
        <div class="layout__item u-1/6">
          <a href="/rm-new-nda">
            <input type="button" id="create-new-nda" class="btn btn--primary" value="Request New NDA" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="found" class="searchResult">
      <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout__item u-1">
          <p>Applicable NDA found for "{{filterValue}}". New NDA not required.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

I have no idea how to do this. Can someone please help here.

Here is the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/iArppZ5ODDyCGvCF5pIp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can use [iron-pages](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages) element to create the appearance of two distinct pages.  If you really need it to be a different url for the results, I would recommend trying out the new [app-route elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route).  Ideally, the search page and the search results page would probably be their own elements, rather than hard coded divs like they are here, but you get the idea.

```
    <dom-module id="my-demo">
      <template>
        <iron-pages selected="[[currentPage]]">
          <div>
            <select value="{{searchTeam::change}}">
              <option value="Jacob">Jacob</option>
              <option value="Edward">Edward</option>
            </select>
            <button on-tap="doSearch">search</button>
            <ul><template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}"><li>{{item.name}} {{item.team}}</li></template></ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Search Results</h2>
            <ul><template is="dom-repeat" items="{{searchResults}}"><li>{{item.name}} {{item.team}}</li></template></ul>
            <button on-tap="goHome">Back to Search</button>
          </div>
        </iron-pages>
      </template>
      <script>
        var data = [
          {name: 'foo', team: 'Jacob'},
          {name: 'bar', team: 'Edward'},
          {name: 'baz', team: 'Jacob'},
          {name: 'qux', team: 'Edward'}
        ]
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-demo',
          ready: function () {
            this.data = data
          },
          properties: {
            searchTeam: {
              type: String,
              value: 'Edward'
            },
            searchResults: {
              type: Array
            },
            currentPage: {
              type: Number,
              value: 0
            }
          },
          doSearch: function () {
            this.searchResults = this.data.filter(function (item) { return item.team === this.searchTeam }.bind(this))
            this.currentPage = 1
          },
          goHome: function () { this.currentPage = 0 }
        })
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```